# Show only the legend of the selected elements when downloading the png of a plotly chart

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

I have a line chart in `plotly` with multiple lines and I would like to download a png of the chart from the button:
[image]

I would like that only the legend of the selected items is shown in the download instead of all of them.

This is my code:

```
chart2 <- plot_ly(x = Dates, y =IP, type = 'scatter',  mode = 'lines', name = "", line = list(color = ) ) %>% 
            add_trace(y = CG,  name = "A", line = list(color = )) %>% 
            add_trace(y = MC,  name = "B", line = list(color = ), visible="legendonly") %>% 
            add_trace(y = MF,  name = "C", line = list(color = ), visible="legendonly") %>% 
            add_trace(y = MM,  name = "D", line = list(color = ), visible="legendonly") %>% 
            add_trace(y = MV,  name = "E", line = list(color = ), visible="legendonly") %>% 
            add_trace(y = MO,  name = "F", line = list(color = ),visible="legendonly") %>% 
            add_trace(y = OM,  name = "G", line = list(color =  ), visible="legendonly") %>% 
            add_trace(y = RI,  name = "H", line = list(color =  ), visible="legendonly") 

chart2 %>% 
  config(toImageButtonOptions = list(
      format= 'png',       filename= '',
      height= 340,
      width= 377,
      scale= 1),
      modeBarButtonsToRemove = list('autoScale', 'select2d', 'lasso2d'), displaylogo = FALSE) %>% 
      layout(legend = list(x = 0.2, y= 2.1,  xanchor = "center", orientation = 'h', tracegroupgap = 0, font = list(size = 9)))
```

Some series of data are the following:

```
  [1]  92.1  93.2  93.6  94.7  96.0  94.7  95.8  95.9  96.0  96.2  97.1  97.8  96.9  97.3  96.8  95.9  96.2  96.2  94.4  96.8  95.5  94.2  93.5  94.2  94.2  94.5  95.3  95.1  95.5  95.9  95.2
 [32]  95.6  95.9  95.3  95.9  94.4  96.0  96.1  95.4  95.8  94.2  94.2  95.8  94.7  94.4  96.8  96.5  96.8  96.7  97.2  96.9  97.8  97.8  97.8  98.7  96.6  98.1  98.6  97.5  97.5  98.3  98.1
 [63]  98.0  99.4  98.1  99.0  99.5  98.3  99.7  99.9 101.6 100.5 101.2 101.2 102.0 102.3 103.8 103.7 103.5 103.8 103.9 103.6 104.6 106.2 105.6 106.3 106.9 105.4 107.3 107.4 107.6 108.4 107.9
 [94] 108.7 108.1 108.5 109.5 109.3 108.8 110.1 106.9 107.0 106.1 105.6 104.8 102.3  98.5  94.9  91.0  89.0  87.8  86.6  88.7  89.2  89.4  89.5  91.6  91.3  91.5  91.5  93.1  92.6  94.3  94.7
[125]  96.5  96.6  96.2  97.0  97.2  98.0  98.9  99.6  99.1 100.1 100.2  99.8 100.4  99.0 100.0 100.1  99.1  98.8  99.1  98.5  97.7  98.4  98.2  97.4  98.3  97.4  97.7  98.4  96.6  95.8  95.1
[156]  95.6  95.2  95.3  96.4  96.6  96.8  96.8  96.0  96.4  96.6  96.1  97.4  97.2  96.9  97.6  97.0  98.6  97.8  97.3  98.1  96.4  97.4  97.1  96.8  98.2  97.6 100.3 100.4  99.4 100.2 100.4
[187] 100.9  99.7 100.3 100.8  99.9 100.1 102.7 101.1 100.6 101.6 100.2 101.2 101.1 101.2 101.4 102.9 102.6 102.5 101.9 102.7 102.4 103.2 103.6 103.2 104.7 105.5 104.9 105.9 107.8 108.1 105.8
[218] 105.0 105.2 104.9 106.3 106.0 104.6 106.2 105.3 106.2 104.3 104.6 105.6 105.5 105.5 105.0 105.4 104.5 103.9 104.4 104.5 105.0 103.8 101.8 104.2 104.0  92.6  75.1  85.3  93.8  97.8  98.3
[249]  98.9 101.3 105.4 104.3 105.8 104.2 105.0 106.2 103.8 104.0 106.1 103.3 102.6 101.7 104.5 105.9 105.0 105.6 103.8 103.9 105.0 106.2 103.8


  [1]  60.4  61.3  60.4  64.3  67.2  67.3  69.6  70.5  68.1  72.2  70.1  68.4  68.9  74.7  68.1  66.1  64.0  61.8  57.7  58.5  59.6  55.5  55.7  57.1  52.4  54.6  56.8  54.2  54.3  56.0  55.7
 [32]  56.8  57.3  55.1  56.4  54.4  56.6  56.5  55.3  58.3  58.2  57.6  59.0  56.6  57.1  61.2  59.3  61.0  59.9  60.1  60.8  60.1  61.4  67.3  64.0  61.6  62.5  63.9  62.8  69.2  65.4  65.4
 [63]  64.2  65.5  64.1  63.8  64.7  66.4  67.2  67.1  68.3  67.6  69.6  68.4  68.9  70.5  70.0  72.9  72.5  74.1  72.9  72.9  73.6  75.4  74.3  74.2  73.6  75.6  77.8  76.2  77.0  78.9  78.9
 [94]  79.4  79.0  77.7  80.4  81.2  80.3  79.5  78.7  78.0  78.1  77.7  78.5  77.5  75.3  72.1  65.3  65.8  65.1  62.8  64.2  60.9  59.4  57.9  56.5  57.2  61.5  59.3  59.1  60.8  62.6  63.0
[125]  62.3  62.6  63.0  64.2  63.1  64.4  65.7  65.5  65.6  65.4  63.2  64.0  63.7  63.0  63.9  64.6  63.5  62.8  63.7  62.9  65.5  64.0  64.2  63.3  64.8  64.1  64.8  65.0  62.0  61.8  60.8
[156]  59.9  60.2  61.1  65.5  61.3  62.1  62.5  60.7  60.5  61.0  59.0  60.5  63.1  59.2  60.3  61.0  60.2  60.6  62.5  62.2  62.8  63.6  60.6  60.1  65.4  93.5 109.5 101.5  99.0 102.7  98.6
[187]  99.9 110.1  96.3  95.8  97.2  96.0 116.2  91.2  95.0  97.2  99.6  99.8  99.8  95.1  99.6 111.3  99.8  98.7 100.5 107.3  96.8 105.7 102.0  87.5 106.2 102.6 103.9 107.6 124.7 112.8 106.7
[218] 100.9  89.0 101.6 116.7  98.4 102.8 108.8 106.2 103.8 104.2 102.1 104.9 103.7 104.4 106.4  99.9  89.1 101.5 105.9 113.8 116.7 109.9 104.8 112.4  94.8 106.7  99.8  97.3  92.0 109.7 103.1
[249] 100.6 103.8 158.0 145.8 157.6 161.9 126.4 148.6 133.6 102.5 129.5 128.9 126.3 117.6 123.0 133.9 126.2 126.1 126.6 115.6 122.7 125.9 112.8
```

What can I do?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I edited the post.  is this helpful ?

Comment: So your problem with the legend, not with the selected data.  You want to hide the inactive traces from the legend in which anyone will not observe there is hidden traces in the downloaded image, right?

Comment: Yes, I do not want to show the labels of the non-selected items in the legend when I download it.